# limit of: $\begin{align} \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n} \end{align}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

How to get the limit of:

$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}
\end{align}$

I have formed it to:

$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n(\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n})}{n}
\end{align}$

And tried to use L'Hopital but unfortunately I am not able to get a result with that:

$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dn}(n(\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}))= (\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n})+n\left(  \frac{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{2\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}}  - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\right)$

$g'(x)=\frac{d}{dn} n = 1$

$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} &=
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{(\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n})+n\left(  \frac{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{2\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}}  - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\right)}{1}} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{(\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n})+n\left( 0\right)}{1}} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{(\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n})}{1}} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}-2\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}})}{\frac{1}{n}}} \\
&= 0\\
\end{align}$

Which is wrong. Wolfram says that the limit is $-1$

I appreciate every help :)

Comment: You can't use l'hopital.You have an expression $\infty - \infty$ in the numerator. Rather multiply denumerator and numerator with the square root conjugate.

Comment: Hint:$\lim \sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}=\lim\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}\times \frac{\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: You can extract $\sqrt{n}$ as a common factor from both summands, and then Taylor-expand $\sqrt{1-2x^{-1/2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{-2\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{-2\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}-1+\sqrt{n}}=-1$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain the step $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{-2\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt{n}}$ a bit more detailed, please?

Comment: Look at the comments... Use $(a-b)(a+b) = a^2- b^2$

Comment: Ok, I understand that step now. There is a little thing left. Why is $\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}= \sqrt{n}-1$?

Comment: Your last step is probably a typo. You can't just replace $\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}$ with $\sqrt{n} - 1$. Rather the right approach is divide numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{n} $ to $\dfrac{-2}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{n}}}+1}\to - 1$

Comment: You can replace $\sqrt{n-2\sqrt{n}}$ with $\sqrt{n}-1$, but you should prove $\lim_\infty\sqrt{n^2+a}=\lim_\infty\sqrt{n^2}$ at first!